# Why instructions after atomic operation make execution faster (on AMD CPU)?

Tags: memory, x86-64, cpu-architecture, atomic, amd-processor

I wrote the following test cases to bench some operations:

```
#define BENCH_ROUNDS 1000000000 // 10**9

static volatile UINT64 _test_argument, _test_result;
static _Atomic(UINT64) _test_atom;

// For convenience
#define bench_loop(var) for (UINT64 var = 0; var < BENCH_ROUNDS; var++)

// Just for reference
VOID test_empty(VOID) {
    bench_loop (i);
}

// Just for reference
VOID test_calc(VOID) {
    UINT64 res = _test_argument;
    bench_loop (i) {
        res += i;
    }
    _test_result = res;
}

VOID test_store(VOID) {
    bench_loop (i) {
        _test_result = i;
    }
}

VOID test_modify(VOID) {
    _test_result = _test_argument;
    bench_loop (i) {
        _test_result += i;
    }
}

VOID test_modify__calc(VOID) {
    _test_result = _test_argument;
    UINT64 res = _test_argument;
    bench_loop (i) {
        _test_result += i;
        res += i;
    }
    _test_result = res;
}

VOID test_atom_modify(VOID) {
    bench_loop (i) {
        _test_atom += i;
    }
}

VOID test_atom_modify__calc(VOID) {
    UINT64 res = _test_argument;
    bench_loop (i) {
        _test_atom += i;
        res += i;
    }
    _test_result = res;
}

VOID test_atom_modify__calc2(VOID) {
    UINT64 res = _test_argument;
    bench_loop (i) {
        _test_atom += i;
        res += i, res ^= i;
        res += i, res ^= i;
        res += i, res ^= i;
        res += i, res ^= i;
    }
    _test_result = res;
}
```

They are wrapped with `QueryPerformanceCounter` to get execution times and compiled with `gcc -Wall -Og -m64 ...` (won't eliminate predictable loops). The results given by an AMD Ryzen 7 4800H CPU @4.3GHz are like:

```
000233.787ms  test_empty
000467.274ms  test_calc
000233.846ms  test_store
001869.585ms  test_modify
001869.459ms  test_modify__calc
004102.050ms  test_atom_modify
004102.818ms  test_atom_modify__calc
003928.742ms  test_atom_modify__calc2
```

The outcome looks mostly reasonable (at least acceptable), except for the last one, where I have no ideas on what happened. I have tested multiple times, and `test_atom_modify__calc2` always runs faster than other `test_atom_modify`s, for about 150~200ms (which is less than 1 clock cycle for each iteration). I also tested a similar `test_modify__calc2` but it won't have such speed-up.

So why does such speed-up exist? Thanks in advance!

---

For reference, here is the assembly of some loops.

```
# test_modify:
    jmp .L11
.L12:
    movq    _test_result(%rip), %rdx
    addq    %rax, %rdx
    movq    %rdx, _test_result(%rip)
    addq    $1, %rax
.L11:
    cmpq    $999999999, %rax
    jbe .L12

# test_atom_modify:
    jmp .L20
.L21:
    lock addq   %rax, _test_atom(%rip)
    addq    $1, %rax
.L20:
    cmpq    $999999999, %rax
    jbe .L21

# test_atom_modify__calc:
    jmp .L23
.L24:
    lock addq   %rax, _test_atom(%rip)
    addq    %rax, %rdx
    addq    $1, %rax
.L23:
    cmpq    $999999999, %rax
    jbe .L24

# test_atom_modify__calc2:
    jmp .L26
.L27:
    lock addq   %rdx, _test_atom(%rip)
    addq    %rdx, %rax
    xorq    %rdx, %rax
    addq    %rdx, %rax
    xorq    %rdx, %rax
    addq    %rdx, %rax
    xorq    %rdx, %rax
    addq    %rdx, %rax
    xorq    %rdx, %rax
    addq    $1, %rdx
.L26:
    cmpq    $999999999, %rdx
    jbe .L27
```

And here is a wrapping program could be used to measure times.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>

#include <Windows.h>

/* Paste test code here! */


static VOID bench_time(VOID (*func)(VOID)) {
    UINT64 freq, st, ed;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER*) &freq);

    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*) &st);
    (*func)();
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*) &ed);

    UINT64 t = ed - st;
    printf("%010.3lfms\n", t * 1000.0 / freq);
}

INT main() {
    _test_argument = GetCurrentProcessId();
    atomic_init(&_test_atom, 0);

    bench_time(&test_empty);
    bench_time(&test_calc);
    bench_time(&test_store);
    bench_time(&test_modify);
    bench_time(&test_modify__calc);
//  bench_time(&test_modify__calc2);
    bench_time(&test_atom_modify);
    bench_time(&test_atom_modify__calc);
    bench_time(&test_atom_modify__calc2);

    return 0;
}
```

Update: To compare, I just ran these on an Intel Xeon E5-2643 v3 CPU, and its results do not show strange speed-up.
<sub>(Loops are decreased to 1 million times, and sleeps are added between tests, because I cannot fix its frequency.)</sub>

```
000000.835ms  test_empty
000000.836ms  test_calc
000000.836ms  test_store
000006.264ms  test_modify
000006.264ms  test_modify__calc
000015.926ms  test_atom_modify
000015.873ms  test_atom_modify__calc
000015.900ms  test_atom_modify__calc2
```

Comment: Which AMD CPU?  Zen 4?  Zen 1? Bulldozer?  Jaguar?  I guess Zen 3 or later since your `test_store` is about twice as fast as `test_calc`.  But wait, GCC doesn't unroll loops, and both have a loop-carried dependency through integer addition (1 cycle latency), so IDK if that's 2 stores per clock or not.  Probably not Zen 2 or 4, if Zen their zero-latency store-forwarding works on RIP-relative addressing modes (https://www.agner.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=41)

Comment: show how you measure the time (main function too)

Comment: @PeterCordes But actually it's Zen 2 (Ryzen 7 4800H Mobile APU). I'll add it in the question and put the assembly of the whole loop later.

Comment: Ok, zero-latency store forwarding doesn't work with RIP-relative addressing modes (or absolute), according to Agner's testing on Zen 2 as he said in the post I linked. :P  IDK why your `test_calc` is slow compared to store, unless it's a front-end effect like splitting a loop across two uop-cache lines.  The store test is as fast as empty, but that's normal, 1/clock store.

Comment: You can use more aggresive optimization options using this trick: https://godbolt.org/z/3baY16G11

Comment: @gulpr that won't affect the times though (at least on my machine), if the loops are not eliminated by `-O3`.

Comment: @WildernessRanger also show how you measure the execution time (basically the main function). MAybe the secret is there.

Comment: Anyway, the `atomic_modify__calc2` test makes me think of [Why is ONE basic arithmetic operation in for loop body executed SLOWER THAN TWO arithmetic operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62089260) / [Adding a redundant assignment speeds up code when compiled without optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49189685) - Sandybridge-family store forwarding is lower latency if you don't try to read the value again so soon.  But that's for normal accesses, this is for `lock`ed, and I don't know if AMD has a similar effect.

Comment: There might be some kind of don't-try-too-soon effect for atomic RMWs on Zen 2, but I don't have a guess at the microarchitectural reason.

Comment: @gulpr I've attached it.

Comment: @WildernessRanger not usable by me as I do not use windows

Comment: Secondary effect of lock latency, search for it in https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Agner Fog lists `lock add` latency for Zen 2 as `~17` cycles, no mention of it being variable.  (And the phrase "lock latency" doesn't appear in that PDF or his microarch PDF.)  There are two independent loop-carried dependency chains here, one through registers with `add` and `xor` instructions on `res` in RAX (8 cycles), the other on a memory location.  (And a third dep chain, 1 cycle latency for `i += 1` with an `add` into RDX.  The other two dep chains each read from this, but it can get far ahead of either of them, of course.)

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: The effect here is that independent ALU operations appear to be shortening the critical path latency bottleneck of `lock addq   %rdx, _test_atom(%rip)`.  Or making the CPU run at a higher clock speed?  IDK if that's plausible, OP hasn't reported core clock frequency during each test.  (AFAIK, QueryPerformanceCounter is just software timing, not hardware PMU performance counters for events like `cpu_clk_unhalted.thread` which would let you calculate CPU frequency.)  You'd hope the CPU wouldn't downclock on loops with no off-core communication.

Comment: @PeterCordes I hope nothing ;-), I am so astonished by what modern processors do and that it is mostly beyond common understanding.

Comment: Or some kind of power management daemon that maybe cranks up the clock speed after 10 seconds at high CPU load?  Not sure how Windows works in this regard.

Comment: @NateEldredge Maybe no… Lifting those functions to the beginning gives almost identical outcome.

Comment: @PeterCordes I just added some information and also tested it on one Intel CPU.