# x86_64. How can I avoid memory dereferencing taking 390 processor cycles instead of 3.6 or at most 10 times more (36 cycles) instead of 100 times more

Tags: memory, x86-64, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

Trying to optimize concurrent linked lists access, I tried to benchmark the average time that dereferencing takes in x86_64 (my specific processor is a Ryzen).

While I knew that the nice old days of one cycle per instruction have gone, I didn't suspect what I would get from the benchmark and I was extremely surprised!

The results show that:

1. nearby successive memory accesses take on average 3.6 processor cycles.
2. less nearby 4.5 , 8.3 , 16 , 126 , 177 , 336 , 340 ... up to 390 cycles per ONE memory access ON AVERAGE.

It is obvious than that something doesn't go as expected, and that almost no body takes into consideration these factors when programming at least to my knowledge.

My question is a VERY SPECIFIC PROGRAMMING QUESTION:

Continuing to use my processor ( AMD or Intel x86_64 architecture ) and continuing to use my OS ( Ubuntu ), do I have any possibility to run the above test and be able to dereference at most 10 times slower than the 3.6 cycles, instead than the 110 times slower that the benchmark shows ? **Whatever it takes to do it !!!**

It is obvious that structures where the data are scattered over a big memory space are frequent and necessary, so a solution should be found to be able to dereference memory without the above extreme delay of 110 times slower.

Bellow is the code that implements the above benchmarks and shows the results.

https://godbolt.org/z/9GEWe4cdd

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdint>

#define repeat_0x10(x) x x x x  x x x x  x x x x  x x x x 
#define repeat_0x100(x) repeat_0x10(repeat_0x10(x))
#define repeat_0x1000(x) repeat_0x100(repeat_0x10(x))

const int loopn=0x4000;
#define asmTimes 0x100
#define tt(x) repeat_0x100(x)

#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int64_t aaa=0x0;

typedef void fT();

// given a function the bench0 executes it for n times returning the number of processor clock ticks that were necessary to execute it. 
// morover before hand it loads the register R15 with the address of variable aaa
auto bench0(fT f,size_t n=loopn){
    auto s1=__rdtsc();
        asm ("lea %0,%%r15" : : "m" (aaa));
        for(int i=n;i--!=0;) f();
    auto s2=__rdtsc();
    return s2-s1;
}
// given a function formed from rep number of repetitions of code, it loops over it for n times and returns a float giving the number of clocks necessary for each single repeated code.
auto bench(fT f,size_t n=loopn,size_t rep=asmTimes){
    return (float)bench0(f,n)/n/rep;
}

#define countof(A) (sizeof(A)/sizeof(*A))

void* P[0x1000000];

// a linked list is formed, sequential entries in the linked list are distant "step" 
void initP(size_t step){
    void* p=nullptr;
    for(size_t i=0;i!=step;i++)
    for(size_t j=0;j!=countof(P);j+=step){*(P+j+i)=p;p=P+j+i;}
    p=P+countof(P)-1;
    //for(size_t i=countof(P);i--!=0;)  p=*(void**)p; std::cout<<" p="<<p<<endl;
}

void walkP(){repeat_0x100(asm("mov (%r15),%r15");)}

auto cpuFrequency(){
    const int sleepN=500000;
    auto t1=__rdtsc();
        usleep(sleepN);
    auto t2=__rdtsc();
    return double(t2-t1)/(sleepN*1e-6);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    cout<<" cpuFrequency()="<<cpuFrequency()<<" sizeof(void*)="<<sizeof(void*)<<endl;
    
    for(size_t i=0;i<0x10;i++){
        aaa=(uintptr_t)(P+countof(P)-1);
        size_t step=1<<i;
        initP(step);cout<<"bench(walkP("<<step<<"))="<<bench(walkP,0x10000,0x100)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My results have been:

```c++
cpuFrequency()=3.69355e+09 sizeof(void*)=8
 p=0
bench(walkP(1))=3.6146
 p=0
bench(walkP(2))=4.48525
 p=0
bench(walkP(4))=8.33419
 p=0
bench(walkP(8))=16.4063
 p=0
bench(walkP(16))=126.335
 p=0
bench(walkP(32))=177.424
 p=0
bench(walkP(64))=336.674
 p=0
bench(walkP(128))=340.422
 p=0
bench(walkP(256))=350.896
 p=0
bench(walkP(512))=360.694
 p=0
bench(walkP(1024))=362.763
 p=0
bench(walkP(2048))=367.925
 p=0
bench(walkP(4096))=391.085
 p=0
bench(walkP(8192))=386.941
 p=0
bench(walkP(16384))=398.989
 p=0
bench(walkP(32768))=389.542
```

Answer (score 1):

**Memory is slow.  Caches work (most of the time).**  The only thing you could do to change the *ratio* is to slow your CPU clock down a *lot* so memory latency is many fewer core cycles.  But obviously that wouldn't make anything faster!

Try to write code that avoids the worst case (L3 cache miss) most of the time.  See also [How much of ‘What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory’ is still valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126311/how-much-of-what-every-programmer-should-know-about-memory-is-still-valid/47714514#47714514) (almost all of it; go read Ulrich Drepper's excellent article.)

But keep in mind that lots of other work can happen during those 390 cycles, including other cache-miss loads (memory pipelining with hit-under-miss and miss-under-miss allowing multiple cache misses to be in flight at once).  Unless you write code like this which does nothing except bottleneck on load *latency* (not throughput).  (See also *[What considerations go into predicting latency for operations on modern superscalar processors and how can I calculate them by hand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51607391/what-considerations-go-into-predicting-latency-for-operations-on-modern-supersca)* / https://agner.org/optimize/ *[Assembly - How to score a CPU instruction by latency and throughput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52260625/assembly-how-to-score-a-cpu-instruction-by-latency-and-throughput)*)

And especially, see [Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide!](https://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/) for more about what's changed since the bad old days when non-pipelined CPUs like 386 didn't even run 1 instruction per cycle, or since scalar pipelines like MIPS could sustain at best 1.

---

**This is why linked lists are slow to iterate through on modern systems,** especially when they're allocated non-sequentially; **prefer arrays** so the next address isn't dependent on the previous load result. Then you'll see a Ryzen CPU able to run 2 loads per clock cycle on Zen1/2, or 3 per cycle on Zen3/4.  (https://uops.info/ measures throughput, latency, and uops.)

Tree-based data structures suffer from this, too, but as long as they're balanced, the depth is only log2(size), rather than linear in size.  Implicit trees (or binary search of an array) can calculate ahead of time where the next access will be, as long as branch prediction is correct.  (Unless the compiler makes branchless assembly, then you have a data dependency on the load result.)

---

Also note that Zen's load-use latency is actually 4 core cycles.  You're measuring 3.6 *reference* cycles.  The reference clock speed is often similar to the non-boost (aka turbo) frequency, so probably your Ryzen clocked itself up to about 1.11x the base frequency while running your test.  See *[How to get the CPU cycle count in x86_64 from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772567/how-to-get-the-cpu-cycle-count-in-x86-64-from-c/51907627#51907627)* for more about the TSC.

Comment: I suppose there should be a reason and a solution to avoid that delays. 110 times more is extremely tooooo much! There is something different that alters the results!

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis: No, your results look about right for load-use latency (pointer chasing) for L1d hits vs. L3 miss all the way to DRAM.  This huge latency ratio is why modern x86 CPUs have 3 levels of cache as n between the cores and DRAM (and the interconnect between multiple cores and the memory controllers also has some latency).  See [Why is the size of L1 cache smaller than that of the L2 cache in most of the processors?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38549736).

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis: And if you haven't read https://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/ yet, do so now.  Its section on "Memory & The Memory Wall" explains how this problem is fundamental as CPUs have gotten faster (higher throughput and higher clock speeds), but it hasn't been possible to reduce *latency* nearly much.  (Although Apple M1 integrating the DRAM into the package helps; go buy one if you want.)

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis:  Also remember you're benchmarking the worst case, where out-of-order execution can't help hide memory latency because of a poor choice of data-structure.  Real code is mostly not like this.  One of the major reasons for CPUs to have deep out-of-order exec buffers is to hide memory latency.

Comment: I will read your references and be back, ! Thanks!

Comment: I have been tracking the relative performance of memory and compute for over 30 years, and 390 core cycles is completely reasonable for pointer chasing loads to main memory with processors in the range of 2.5 to 3 GHz.  This was covered in https://sites.utexas.edu/jdm4372/2016/11/22/sc16-invited-talk-memory-bandwidth-and-system-balance-in-hpc-systems/ particularly in slides 13-15.  A more recent update shows the same sorts of trends: https://hpc.fau.de/files/2021/12/memorybw_systembalance_slides_2021-12-15.pdf